# What is the most efficient way to create a reservoir in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am creating a 3D reservoir model which looks like this.

[image]

It's made of hundreds of thousands of cells with outline. The outline is needed for all cells underneath, because there is an IJK filter used to hide cells on any level and thus show the rest. Once the model is rendered, it shouldn't need to be updated in terms of position or scale.

That's enough about the background. The approach I'm using is creating one large geometry, which stores all vertices cross the reservoir in one triangle strip. It also stores IJK index for each cell, so the IJK filter works in shader level. This should create the mesh part. Then I create another object to draw all outlines using one `THREE.LineSegments`.

The approach works pretty well for small amount of cells, but for large data set, frame rate drops.

I'm proposing another way of doing this by barycentric outline and instancing drawing. [Barycentric outline drawing](http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/) removes the extra LineSegment object, since it draws outline in fragment shader. However, it comes with drawbacks. Because of the missing of geometry shader in WebGL, I have to use full triangle rather than triangle strip to store barycentric coordinates for each vertex. I'm ok with this extra memory usage, if instanced drawing can boost the performance.(?) That's to say, I draw a cube with outline, and I create as many instances as I need and put them in right position.

I am wondering if this approach is indeed gonna increase the performance theoretically. Any thoughts are welcomed!

Comment: I recommend you use the [Three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) for this type of open-ended, non-specific questions. But yes, using `InstancedBufferGeometry` leads to better performance due to the reduced number of drawcalls per frame. [See here for examples of instancing](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instancing#webgl_instancing_suzanne).

Comment: Your image doesn't show 100s of thousands of cells. Maybe you should pre-process your data to be simple like shown in the image you posted

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I am gonna answer this question myself.
I implemented the change based on above ideas and it works pretty good compared to the original version.

Let's put the result first: this approach has no problem rendering hundreds of thousands of cells at reasonable frame rate. My demo contains 400,000 cells, with the frame rate at 50 fps in worst case, running on my Nvidia 1050Ti card and 4k monitor. For comparison, if I draw 400,000 cells in the previous version, the frame rate could drop to 10 fps.

This means using instanced drawing for a large object is faster than composing a single large geometry. For rendering performance, the instanced cube is rendered only one side, while triangle-stripped cube is two-sided. Once I can draw a single unit cube with ideal outline, I can transform it to any places in "any" shape in vertex shader. But of course instanced drawing comes with its restrictions: each cell doesn't have to be at same shape, but has to have same number of vertices, faces, etc; I lost control to change vertex color...

As for memory usage, the new approach actually use less. I provide position for 8 vertices, instead of 14, in each cell. Even though the first unit cube has 36 vertices, I can use its unit position as index, for subsequent instances. That is, for 36 unit vertices (0/1, 0/1, 0/1), I only need to provide 8 real positions.

Hope this helps for people who want to implement the same optimization.